# Automating Kubernetes deployment using script

Tags: kubernetes, scripting, minikube, kubernetes-pod

I have 'deployment.yaml' & 'service.yaml' files to deploy application in kubernetes (minikube).

To do a manual deployment I can use `kubectl apply -f <file.yaml>`  to create resources but I am looking for a way to automate  deployment using scripts. So I can trigger a script and all the  needed yaml can be triggered and pods created accordingly.

Any suggestion or guidance will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you need some simple bash script where you put all commands you need

```
#!/bin/bash

NAMESPACE='mebbns'
DEPL_DIR='~/mebb_depl'
SVC_DIR='~/svc_depl'

kubectl create namespace $NAMESPACE 
kubectl apply -n $NAMESPACE -f "$DEPL_DIR/deployment.yaml"
kubectl apply -n $NAMESPACE -f "$SVC_DIR/service.yaml"
kubectl get all -n $NAMESPACE
```

For more complex tasks you can check examples like  [setup-aks-vnet-acr.sh](https://github.com/RoyKimYYZ/linux-scripts/blob/master/setup-aks-vnet-acr.sh)

[kubectl Cheat Sheet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/) should help you with basic commands you may require.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a script to call kubectl for simple scenarious.
For more complex setups have a look at Argo cd https://argoproj.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to automate your task. Any scripting language would be alright; such as `Bash`, `Ansible`, etc. If you are looking for sophisticated deployment tools, you can have a look at the [common Kubernetes CI/CD tools](https://cloud.redhat.com/blog/top-open-source-ci/cd-tools-for-kubernetes-to-know)

Kubernetes automation doesn't end with the CI/CD. When you have multiple applications with each of them has specific environment variables, security credentials, specific network and security requirements etc., then you will also need [tools for organizing Kubernetes configuration](https://blog.argoproj.io/the-state-of-kubernetes-configuration-management-d8b06c1205), such as `Helm` and `Kustomize`.